# need help in writing complex sql query with join and with case

Tags: mysql

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90d4ac/8)

**Expected output is below:**

```
id | firstname. | lastname. | country.| followerscount.| followingcount.| BottonText
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54  prince          lal        nepal          1                1            Unfollow
56.  Rekha.       Gupta      United States    1                0            Unfollow
57. Nirmal         null         null          0                1           Follow Back
```

I tried below query assuming current logged in UserId= 55 &  compare with other users. Can you write the correct query, it can be with join, i just need the output,query can be anything

TRY1

```
SELECT
u.user_id AS id, u.first_name AS firstname,u.last_name AS lastname,u.country as country,
(select count(uf.following_user_id) from user_follow uf where uf.followed_user_id=u.user_id)as followerscount,
(select count(uf.followed_user_id) from user_follow uf where uf.following_user_id=u.user_id)as followingcount, 

CASE
    WHEN uuf.following_user_id=55 AND uuf.followed_user_id=u.user_id  THEN "Unfollow" # A is following B == unfollow 
    WHEN uuf.following_user_id=u.user_id AND uuf.followed_user_id NOT IN(55) THEN "Follow Back"  #B is following A but A is not following B = followBack
    ELSE "Follow"
END AS BottonText

FROM userdetails u,user_follow uuf
WHERE u.user_id NOT IN(55) AND u.record_status=1
```

TRY2

```
SELECT
       u.user_id,
       (count(uf.following_user_id)) as followers,
        
   CASE
    WHEN uf.following_user_id=55 AND uf.followed_user_id=u.user_id  THEN "Unfollow" # A is following B == unfollow  
    WHEN uf.following_user_id=u.user_id AND uf.followed_user_id=55 AND uf.following_user_id !=55 AND uf.followed_user_id !=u.user_id
    THEN "Follow Back"  #B is following A but A is not following B = followBack
    ELSE "Follow"
END AS BottonText,
       
      (select count(uf.followed_user_id) 
        from user_follow uf 
      where uf.following_user_id = u.user_id) as following
      from
         (userdetails u left outer join user_follow uf on uf.followed_user_id=u.user_id)  
         where   u.record_status=1 and u.user_id NOT IN(55)
         group by  u.user_id
```

Table defination

```
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `country` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `avatar_img_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `record_status` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1- active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `userdetails`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);
   

CREATE TABLE `user_follow` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `following_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followed_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
 #following_user_id and followed_user_id are foriegn key associated  userdetails user_id
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90d4ac/18

schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `country` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `avatar_img_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `record_status` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1- active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `userdetails`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);
  
  
INSERT INTO `userdetails` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `country`, `avatar_img_name`, `record_status`) VALUES
(1, 'Admin', 'Admin', 'India', NULL, 0),
(54, 'Prince', 'Lal', 'Nepal', 'p.jpg', 1),
(55, 'ashutosh', 'Singh', 'Afganistan', 'a.jpg', 1),
(56, 'Rekha', 'Gupta', 'United States', 'r.jpg', 1),
(57, 'Nirmal', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);



CREATE TABLE `user_follow` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `following_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followed_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `user_follow` (`id`, `following_user_id`, `followed_user_id`, `created_date`) VALUES
(1, 55, 56, '2021-02-07 02:14:26'),
(2, 55, 54, '2021-02-06 01:14:26'),
(3, 54, 55, '2021-02-07 10:33:45'),
(4, 57, 55, '2021-02-07 00:00:00');

ALTER TABLE `user_follow`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `following_user_id` (`following_user_id`),
  ADD KEY `followed_user_id` (`followed_user_id`);
  
  ALTER TABLE `user_follow`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;


ALTER TABLE `user_follow`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_follow_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`followed_user_id`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_follow_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`following_user_id`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

query:

```sql
SELECT
  u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.country, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_follow uf1 WHERE uf1.followed_user_id=u.user_id) AS followerscount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_follow uf2 WHERE uf2.following_user_id=u.user_id) AS followingcount,
  IF(
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_follow uf3 -- if I'm following the specified user
           WHERE uf3.following_user_id=55 AND uf3.followed_user_id=u.user_id), 
    'Unfollow', -- then show 'unfollow button'
    IF(
      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_follow uf4 -- if the specified user is following me
           WHERE uf4.followed_user_id=55 AND uf4.following_user_id=u.user_id),
      'Follow Back', -- then show 'follow back button'
      'Follow') -- then show 'follow button'
  ) AS ButtonText
FROM
  userdetails u
WHERE 
  u.user_id<>55 
  AND u.user_id<>1 -- should not select the admin user
```

explanation: it seems that the expected table is based on "userdetails" table, so you should only select "userdetails" in FROM clause, and add other column with subquery in SELECT clause

Comment: There is also `Follow` to be display as ButtonText, you are missing